# Why my function Mask does not apply?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, controls

I use the Mask function for my fields ( ex. telephone numbers) to force the user to only enter that figures .
The mask applies well, IF When I write my field and the mask on the once page .
But, Mask Do Not applicable , WHhen I write the field and Mask on two different pages, THESE ARE THE linked by using the AjaxRequest function.

Where Should I Put the mask of control ?
thank you

```js
   $(function()
   {
    // Masking
    $("#tel_struct").mask('(33) 9-99-99-99-99', {placeholder:'X'});
    $("#fax_struct").mask('(33) 9-99-99-99-99', {placeholder:'X'});
    $("#postalcodeInput").mask('99999', {placeholder:'X'});
    
    // Validation
    $("#sky-form").validate(
    {     
     // Règles de validation
     rules:
     {
      nom_contact:
      {
       required: false
      },
      famille_contact:
      {
       required: true
      },
      typologie:
      {
       required: true
      },
      thematique:
      {
       required: true
      },
      tel_struct:
      {
       required: true 
      },
      mail_struct:
      {
       required: true 
      },
      country:
      {
       required: true
      },
      postalcode:
      {
       required: true
      },
      place:
      {
       required: true
      },
      fax_pers:
      {
       //digits: true
      },
      
     },
          
     // Messages pour validation
     messages:
     {
      nom_contact:
      {
       required: 'Saisissez le nom du contact'
      },
      famille_contact:
      {
       required: 'Veuillez sélectionner le famille de contact'
      },
      typologie:
      {
       required: 'Veuillez sélectionner une typologie'
      },
      thematique:
      {
       required: 'Veuillez sélectionner une thématique'
      },
      mail_struct:
      {
       required: 'Saisissez une adresse email',
       email: 'Entrez une adresse email valide'
      },
      tel_struct:
      { required: 'Saisissez un numéro de téléphone',
       digit: 'Entrez seulement des chiffres'
      },
      fax_struct:
      {
       digit: 'Entrez seulement des chiffres'
      },
      country:
      {
       required: 'Sélectionner le pays',
      },
      postalcode:
      {
       required: 'Saisissez le code postal',
      },
      place:
      {
       required: 'Saisissez la ville',
      },
      fax_pers:
      {
       digit: 'Entrez seulement des chiffres'
      },
      
     },
          
     // Ajax form submition     
     submitHandler: function(form)
     {
      $(form).ajaxSubmit(
      {
       beforeSend: function()
       {
        $('#sky-form button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', true);
       },
       success: function()
       {
        $("#sky-form").addClass('submited');
       }
      });
     },
     
     // Do not change code below
     errorPlacement: function(error, element)
     {
      error.insertAfter(element.parent());
     }
    });
   });
```

```html
<html >
<head>

  
  <!-- Fonction JQUERY Auto-complete -->  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min (2).js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script (2).js"></script>
  <!-- FIN JQUERY Auto complete--> 
  
  <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
 <body class="bg-red" onload="setDefaultCountry();">
 <!--Form------------------------------------------->
  <div class="body">
   <form action="" method="post" id="sky-form" class="sky-form">
<!-- Button that calls the second page , which contains the phone number field-->
              <h4 style="cursor:pointer" onclick="ajaxrequest('lecture_structure.php', 'message')"><u>Rechercher</u></h4>
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please take some time to write correctly and formulate comprehensible sentences.

Comment: Okay, sorry. I have a form which contains any fields, and I would like to do controls for these fields. So, I'd like to use $("#telephone").mask('(33) 9-99-99-99-99', {placeholder:'X'}); to control the field of telephone. This is the purpose. Now, I know that this Mask works correctly in a simple page. But, in my page, my form is divided in two "forms", exactly, I have a field of search, for search a name in my data base, then after found the name, the following fields will be displayed –

Comment: so you're saying that the mask works on one input field, but not two?

Comment: No,I want to say that the mask works for all fields in one situation when I write all fields and the mask in the same page.

Comment: But, in my situation, I write the mask in page, and the fields in other page.

Comment: I still don't get it. Mask is in javascript, and the fields are in HTML, right? So, if the javascript works for page 1, then why don't you simply apply the same javascript on page 2?

Comment: I tried, but it does not work. The fields are built in HTML that are integrated in a PHP with echo.

Comment: This is not relevant. Javascript doesn't care what generates the HTML server-side. It can be PHP or ASP or whatever, all there is client-side is HTML. JS acts on HTML. Page 1 : put your script, it works; page 2 : put your script, it works. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: I want to keep the two pages as they are (with the call ajaxrequest), like that, the mask does not work. The mask is only my first page, the second is just called.

Comment: I want to make a point. My other controls I.e. "Required" and "control of email" work perfectly. So, why the mask does not work like that?

Comment: I think I get it. You're loading the second page, via ajax, into the first one, is that it? In that case, it's normal that the mask doesn't work. you have to apply it again after page 2 is loaded. If that's still not it, sorry :)

Comment: Yes, that's right! So, I have to write the mask in the page 2 ?

Comment: Well no. Load the PHP page via ajax, and in the callback function, apply the mask on it.

Comment: Okay, thanks :) I have already this line : onclick="ajaxrequest('lecture_structure.php', 'message') for call my second page PHP (lecture_structure), so,  is it not charged?

Comment: What's in the ajaxrequest function? You didn't post the code for it, and it's not part of javascript or jQuery, so I don't know what it does. You should do : `$("#container").load("secondPage.php", applyMask)`. `applyMask` is a function that you need to define and that will be called after the php page is loaded (that's the callback function). In there, apply the Mask to the freshly loaded page.

Comment: I have a question, I write that $("#container").load("secondPage.php", applyMask). applyMask  in the ajaxrequest function. But, what is the container, is it my field ? and I must have this function as parameter in ajaxrequest, isn't it ?

Comment: The problem is, as I already mentioned, I don't know what your container is, and I don't know what  the "ajaxrequest" function is. You didn't post anything about that. I just gave you a generic method to properly load a page in a container (div), then apply script to it in the callback function. Obviously, you have to replace `"#container"` with your actual container selector, and `"secondPage.php"` with your actual second page name. See [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: I posted the function ajaxrequest, below. So I write this method into ajaxrequest? like that : `function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) { //instructions ; $("#container").load("lecture_structure.php", applyMask); }`

Comment: Ok I see the function. So the code would be : `function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID){ $(tagId).load(php_file, applyMask) }; function applyMask(){ alert("Applying mask!"); }` That should load the given PHP file into the `tagID` element, then launch `applyMask`, and you should see the alert. Then, write your actual mask code in `applyMask`.

Comment: Thank you! I try that, and  my function autocomplete() does not work, something block in the code.

Comment: After, I put this line `$(tagId).load(php_file, applyMask) }; function applyMask(){ alert("Applying mask!"); }` at the end of the function ajaxrequest, the autocomplete() works but I don't have results, because my button Search does not work.

Comment: Now, it works. Forget what I say :0, I put the instruction at the  end of the function ajaxrequest, but I don't have the alert :(

Comment: Don't put my code _at the end of your function_. It IS the whole function, it's a single line. Use my code and that's it. Your old function takes 20 lines because you wrote it in plain javascript, but jQuery does it in one line. I believe this thread has already gone WAY beyond what a stackovervlow thread should be. If your code still doesn't work, we just can't keep discussing here this way. Try to play around with [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), make some tests and understand wow it works before going any further in your developments.

Comment: Here, I made you a Pen to help you understand. http://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/XbjELL I can't do much more, I mean I can't develop your application along with you, if nothing works and you don't know how to load content and use a callback. Play with these things first, then try and develop an application =)

Comment: Thank you so much :), I understand more. This method allows to load the javascript content, I'll try with this method :-)

Answer (score 0):

Code of my second page (does not appears just called)

```html
Code of my second page (does not appears just called) 
<?php
session_start();
include("connexion.php");
echo "<script src=\"js/jquery.validate.min.js\"></script>";
echo "<script src=\"js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js\"></script>";
/* Méthode PDO */
$id_struct = $_POST['id_struct'];
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM structure WHERE nom_contact='$id_struct'";
$result = $bdd->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($row[0]!=0)
    {
  //echo '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i><br /><font color="red">J\'ai trouvé la structure<br /></font>';
  
 //Lire ou Afficher les données 
$_SESSION['nom_contact']=$id_struct;
//1)on se connecte à la BDD
$reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM structure WHERE nom_contact='$id_struct'");
$donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
//while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
$desc_contact= $donnees['desc_contact'];
$nom_struct= $donnees['nom_struct'];
$nom_service= $donnees['nom_service'];
$adres_struct= $donnees['adres_struct'];
$code_postal= $donnees['code_postal'];
$ville= $donnees['ville'];
$tel_struct= $donnees['tel_struct'];
$fax_struct= $donnees['fax_struct'];
$mail_struct= $donnees['mail_struct']; 
$page_web= $donnees['page_web']; 
$thematique=$donnees['id_thematique'];
$typologie=$donnees['id_typologie'];
$pays=$donnees['id_pays'];

$reponse1 = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM typologie'); 
$donnees1 = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$reponse2 = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM thematique'); 
$donnees2 = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$reponse3 = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM pays'); 
$donnees3 = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo '<fieldset>
 <!--Typologie-->
 <div class="row">
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">';        
         while ($donnees1 = $reponse1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          if ($donnees1["id_typologie"]==$typologie)
          echo' <input type="text" name="typologie" id="typologie" placeholder="Typologie" value="'.$donnees1["typologie"].'" disabled=disabled">
        </label>
        <i></i>';
            
     echo'  </section>
         
      
      <!--Fin Typologie-->
      
      <!--Thématique-->
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="select">
         <select id="thematique" name = "thematique">';
             
             echo '<OPTION VALUE="">Thématique</OPTION>';
              while ($donnees2 = $reponse2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
              {  if ($donnees2["id_thematique"]==$thematique)
              echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$donnees2["id_thematique"].'" selected="selected">'.$donnees2["thematique"].'</OPTION>';
                     else
              echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$donnees2["id_thematique"].'">'.$donnees2["thematique"].'</OPTION>';
             }
        
            
     echo'    </select>
         <i></i>
        </label>
       </section>
      <!--Fin Thématique-->
 </div>    
      <!--Nom du contact-->
       <section>
        <label class="label">Nom du contact</label>
        <label class="textarea">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
         <textarea rows="2" name="nom_contact" id="nom_contact">'.$id_struct.'</textarea>
        </label>
       </section> 
      <!--Fin contact-->
    
      
     
      <!--Description contact-->
       <section>
        <label class="label">Description du contact</label>
        <label class="textarea">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
         <textarea rows="4" name="desc_contact" id="desc_contact">'.$desc_contact.'</textarea>
        </label>
       </section> 
      <!--Fin Description contact-->
     
    </fieldset> 
    
    <fieldset> 
     
      <!--Nom de la structure-->
       <section>
        <label class="input">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-briefcase"></i>
         <input type="text" name="nom_struct" id="nom_struct" placeholder="Nom de la structure" value="'.$nom_struct.'"">
        </label>
        <i></i>
       </section>
      <!--Fin Nom de la structure-->
     
      <!--Nom du service-->
       <section>
        <label class="input">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-briefcase"></i>
         <input type="text" name="nom_service" id="nom_service" placeholder="Nom du service / direction / pole / section de la structure" value="'.$nom_service.'">
        </label>
        <i></i>
       </section>
      <!--Fin Nom de service-->
     
     
      <!-- Adresse complète--> 
       <section>
        <label for="file" class="input">
         <input type="text" name="adres_struct" placeholder="Adresse complète" value="'.$adres_struct.'"">
        </label>
       </section>
      <!-- Fin Adresse complète-->
      <!-- code postal VILLE pays----------------------->   
     <div class="row">
      <section class="col col-3">
       <label class="input">
        <input id="postalcodeInput" name="postalcode" onblur="postalCodeLookup();" size="6" type="text" placeholder="Code Postal" value="'.$code_postal.'"">
       </label>
      </section>
      <section class="col col-4">
       <label class="input">
        <input id="placeInput" name="place" size="30" onblur="closeSuggestBox();" type="text" placeholder="Ville" value="'.$ville.'">
       </label>
       <label class="select">
        <ul class="select" style="visibility: hidden;" id="suggestBoxElement"></ul>
       </label>
      </section>
      <section class="col col-5">
       <label class="select">
        <select id="countrySelect" name="country">';
        echo '<OPTION VALUE="">Pays</OPTION>';
        while ($donnees3 = $reponse3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
             {  if ($donnees3["id_pays"]==$pays)
              echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$donnees3["id_pays"].'" selected="selected">'.$donnees3["pays"].'</OPTION>';
                     else
              echo '<OPTION VALUE="'.$donnees3["id_pays"].'">'.$donnees3["pays"].'</OPTION>';
             }
     echo'
        
        </select>
        <i></i>
       </label>
      </section>
      
     </div>



     
     <div class="row">
      <!--Tél générique-->
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-phone"></i>
          <input type="tel" name="tel_struct" id="tel_struct" placeholder="Téléphone générique" value="'.$tel_struct.'">
        </label>
       </section>
      <!--Fin tél générique-->
     
      <!--Fax générique-->
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-phone"></i>
          <input type="tel" name="fax_struct" id="fax_struct" placeholder="Fax générique" value="'.$fax_struct.'">
        </label>
       </section>
      <!--Fin Fax générique-->
     </div>
     
     <div class="row">
      
      <!--Email générique-->
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
         <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
         <input type="email" name="mail_struct" id="mail_struct" placeholder="Email générique" value="'.$mail_struct.'">
        </label>
       </section>
      <!-- Fin email générique-->
      <!--Page web-->
       <section class="col col-6">
        <label class="input">
         <input type="text" name="page_web" id="page_web" placeholder="Page web" value="'.$page_web.'">
        </label>
        <i></i>
       </section>
      <!--Fin Page web-->
     </div></fieldset>
     ';
     
    }
 else {
  echo "Rien trouvé !";
 }


/*-----Méthode mysql ---
 mysql_connect('localhost','croix_rouge','admin') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('croix_rouge') or die(mysql_error());
 $id_struct = $_POST['id_struct'];
 echo"hello";
    $sql = "SELECT nom_contact FROM structure WHERE nom_contact='$id_struct'";
 echo"hello";
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
 echo"hello";
    $res = mysql_num_rows($req); 
    if($res!=0)
    {
  echo '<i class="fa fa-ban"></i><br /><font color="red">J\'ai trouvé la structure<br /></font>';
    }
 else {
  echo "Rien trouvé !";
 }
*/
echo "<script src=\"js/controles.js\"></script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code of the function AjaxRequest :

```js
    function get_XmlHttp() {
      var xmlHttp = null;

      if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {        // Firefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      else if(window.ActiveXObject) {    // Internet Explorer 5 or 6
        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

      return xmlHttp;
    }

    function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
      var request =  get_XmlHttp();
      var id_struct = document.getElementById('id_struct').value;

      
 var the_data = 'id_struct='+id_struct;
 
   request.open("POST", php_file, true);            

      request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      request.send(the_data);

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
      }
    }
```